# A map of <String, Object> to JSONString

Tags: java, json

```
             ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

         searchCriteria.put(TICKET_STATUS_LIST,
                 mapper.writeValueAsString(ticketStatus));

         String ticketListJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(tkmTicketList);
         String searchCrteriaJson = mapper
                 .writeValueAsString(searchCriteria);

         Map<String, Object> ticketSearchResult = new HashMap<String, Object>();

         ticketSearchResult.put("ticketListJson", ticketListJson);
         ticketSearchResult.put("searchCriteriaJson", searchCrteriaJson);
         ticketSearchResult.put("count", iResultCt);

         return mapper.writeValueAsString(ticketSearchResult);
```

I've come across this delightful code, problem is that the search criteria and ticketListJson end up being treated like strings so I get a crappy json as out:

```
{"count":7,"searchCriteriaJson":"{\"startRecord\":0,\"sortOrder\":\"DESC\",\"ticketStatus\":\"[\\\"Any\\\"]\",\"pageSize\":10,\"sortBy\":\"Default\",\"customer\":1599}","ticketListJson":"[{\"id\":\"30\",\"subject\":\"Test\",\"number\":\"TIC-30\",...
```

How can I have these inner json strings maintain their normal values without it adding a bunch of escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the `searchCriteria` and `tkmTicketList` objects directly into the `ticketSearchResult` map rather than going through the `writeValueAsString` method multiple times. Jackson will walk through the Map and serialize the objects it encounters.

If you needed to do something more complicated with the serialization of those other objects, you could do this: (which I wrote first, then realised it was overkill for what you need)

Convert the `searchCriteria` and `tkmTicketList` to JSON tree nodes rather than strings, and then they will be included in the search result JSON rather than being re-escaped as strings:

```
JsonNode searchCriteriaJson = mapper.convertValue(searchCriteria, JsonNode.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `writeValueAsString()` more than once. Insert `ticketStatus`, `tkmTicketList`, and `searchCriteria` into the maps directly.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

searchCriteria.put(TICKET_STATUS_LIST, ticketStatus);

Map<String, Object> ticketSearchResult = new HashMap<String, Object>();

ticketSearchResult.put("ticketListJson", tkmTicketList);
ticketSearchResult.put("searchCriteriaJson", searchCriteria);
ticketSearchResult.put("count", iResultCt);

return mapper.writeValueAsString(ticketSearchResult);
```